# Auto label points read from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

My question is the following, I read data from txt file where the data are stored as:

```
North,East 
1,5
4,7
```

a file with code

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=true {data.csv}\table;
\addplot [color=black, mark=*, only marks] table[x=East, y=North] from \table;
```

It's possibile to enumerate the point plot in order that 1,2,3,... as the row of txt file

Comment: Welcome to the site. Yes, use `x=\coordindex` instead of the table value

Comment: @percusse Do you want to write an answer for this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use x=\coordindex instead of the table value such that the x coordinate would be the number of coordinate encountered in the table.